# How to get a pk from Django URL into ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have a django url that uses a primary key in it, and I want to be able to reference it in my javascript/ajax snippet. I can't find any examples online though, is this possible or do I need to do something like remove all letters from the url?

urls.py

```
path('survey/<int:pk>/record_question/', QuestionRecordView.as_view(), name='survey-question-record'),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do this. 
Easiest way is the following.

You can always get the url parameter in the template layer by using the syntax {{ param_name }}

So, if your url is

```
path('survey/<int:pk>/record_question/', QuestionRecordView.as_view(), name='survey-question-record'),
```

then use,

```
{{ pk }}
```

in your template HTML file. This will give you access to the url parameter --> pk.

To pass this value to your ajax you can declare this value inside a script tag in your html and then call your ajax function with this as an argument.

eg:

```
<script>
    var pk = {{ pk }} ;
</script>
```

Next you can use this variable in a js file ajax function or in the same html. If you are using a separate js file, just make sure to link that js file to this html.

eg:

```
<script>
    Foo.foo = {
            id = pk
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'id': id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                   your_logic
                }
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```